# Can Spring JDBC DataClassRowMapper / BeanPropertyRowMapper be used as a singleton

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, data-class, rowmapper

Springs DataClassRowMapper seems to be thread safe.

However all examples I see, are constructing new instances on every use.

It is doing reflection on construction, so there is some costs on constructing it.

Can we create singleton instances for DataClassRowMappers per type, and reuse them for every query?

Comment: Yes you could reuse them, no there is no cost in constructing them as there is no reflection at that point., there is some introspection and those results are stored in a cache, so the second time one is constructed there is no overhead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should BeanPropertyRowMapper be singleton or declared in each query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442156/should-beanpropertyrowmapper-be-singleton-or-declared-in-each-query)